# JSONP Ajax Error Jquery(Number String) Not Called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp, mailchimp

Since moving my site to https, the mailchimp api no longer works with the standard json ajax calls. These calls now render a same origin policy error. I don't know why this is the case though, because I'm calling a url on my own server. After some investigating, I've surmised that JSONP is my only option. The following script posts correctly to mailchimp but Im unable to get a successful response.

```
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://mysite/book_subscription_process.php?jsonp=?",
    data:{fname: $('#fNBookId').val(), lname: $('#lNBookId').val(), email: $('#eBookId').val()},//only input
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(data){
    console.log('success');
    if(data.message == 'failure')
    {
     alert('Error','There was an error processing your subscription. Please try again.');
    }else if(data.message == 'success')
    {
       alert('success');
    }else{
     console.log(data.message);
    } 
        },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, data) {
    // console.log(data.message);
  console.log('failure');
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }

    });
```

Server side:

```
     <?php
     header("content-type: text/javascript"); 
     if(isset($_GET['jsonp']))
     {
        $obj->fname = $_GET['fname'];
        $obj->lname = $_GET['lname'];
        $obj->email = $_GET['email'];
        $obj->success = 'success';
        $obj->failure = 'failure';

    }
    header("Content-type: application/json");  


   $MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp($api_key);

   $book = array('id' => $group_id, 'groups' => array('Book'));

   $merge_vars = array('FNAME'=> $obj->fname, 
   'LNAME'=>$obj->lname,
   'GROUPINGS'=>array($book)
    );

    $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
    'id'                => $list_id,
    'email'             => array('email'=>$obj->email),
    'merge_vars'        => $merge_vars,
    'double_optin'      => false,
    'update_existing'   => true,
    'replace_interests' => false,
    'send_welcome'      => false,
    ));
    if ( ! empty( $result['leid'] ) ) {
   echo json_encode($obj->success);
   }
  else{
  echo json_encode($obj->failure);
   }

  ?>
```

As I said above the info is correctly posted to mailchimp. Each time however, the ajax call errors. I get a 200 OK but get a Jquery[bunch of numbers] not called. The json_encode success statement is executed on the server. Is there a special way that I'm supposed to handle the server side response? Or am I supposed to do something differently on the client side? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Same Origin means that the page making the request and the destination server need to have identical protocol, server, and port. For this particular situation, MailChimp isn't either of those -- the page making the request is your HTML page and the server is `https://mysite/book_subscription_process.php`.

Since you said this corresponds to your move to HTTPS, my guess is that you've moved one end but not the other. Since the code above looks like the front-end page is calling `https://mysite`, I'd triple check to make sure that the HTML and all scripts are also being served from `https://mysite`.

I don't think you should need JSONP in this scenario -- it sounds like you are attempting to work from the same origin, you just need to be sure you're doing that properly.